# Finding boundary of object in image python?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I was trying to find the boundary of objects in picture and display the contour on the image, which is my problem. I have the following picture here:

[image: Rice]

I did the following to extract the contour and plot them on the image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('/home/rama/Downloads/rice.jpg')
rsz_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.25, fy=0.25) # resize since image is huge
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rsz_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale
plt.imshow(gray)
# threshold to get just the signature
    cnts, hierarchy= cnts, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(gray.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for contour in cnts:
    print(cv2.boundingRect(contour))
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.imshow('contour', cv2.boundingRect(contour))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This gives me just the image as above, no boundary.

How do I plot the boundaries I found on the image?

EDIT SOLUTION:

I did the following:

```
cnts, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(gray.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for contour in cnts:
    print(cv2.boundingRect(contour))
cv2.drawContours(img,cnts,-1,(125,125,0),3 )
cv2.imshow('contours',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I can see it the first time, when I run it the second time I dont see the image window anymore? I did see the correct boundary the first time!

Comment: What do you mean by "when I run it the second time I dont see the image window anymore"? if you kill the process and start it again does it work? If you call destroyAllWindows() it is normal that they disappear, but if you execute your program again it should work again